# unable to sort react table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table-v8

**here's the entire component**

```
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  SortingState,
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useIntersectionObserver } from "@/hooks";
import {
  Box,
  Flex,
  Text,
  Paper,
  Table,
  Skeleton,
  BoxProps,
  useMantineTheme,
} from "@mantine/core";
import {
  forwardRef,
  ReactNode,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  memo,
} from "react";
import { QueryFunction, useInfiniteQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { RiDatabase2Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

export type FetchFn<T> = (props: { pageParam: number }) => Promise<T[]>;

interface TableComponentProps<T> {
  queryFn: QueryFunction<T[], string[], number>;
  columns: ColumnDef<T, any>[];
  queryKey: any[];
}

const TableComponent: <T>(props: TableComponentProps<T>) => ReactNode = memo(
  ({ queryKey, queryFn, columns }) => {
    const skullComponentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [sortingState, setSortingState] = useState<SortingState>([]);
    const entry = useIntersectionObserver(skullComponentRef, {});
    const isVisible = !!entry?.isIntersecting;
    const { colors } = useMantineTheme();

    const {
      data,
      isLoading,
      fetchStatus,
      hasNextPage,
      isRefetching,
      fetchNextPage,
    } = useInfiniteQuery({
      queryFn,
      initialPageParam: 0,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      staleTime: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1 min
      queryKey: [...queryKey, sortingState],
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allpages) =>
        lastPage.length ? allpages.length : null,
    });

    const scrollPingPong = () => {
      const tableContainer = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>(
        ".mantine-ScrollArea-viewport"
      );
      if (tableContainer && skullComponentRef.current) {
        tableContainer.scrollTop =
          tableContainer.scrollHeight -
          tableContainer.clientHeight -
          skullComponentRef.current.offsetHeight;
        tableContainer.scrollTop =
          tableContainer.scrollHeight - tableContainer.clientHeight;
      }
    };

    const flatData = useMemo(
      () => data?.pages?.flatMap((row) => row) ?? [],
      [data]
    );

    const table = useReactTable({
      columns,
      data: flatData,
      state: { sorting: sortingState },
      onSortingChange: setSortingState,
      getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isVisible && hasNextPage) {
        scrollPingPong();
        fetchNextPage();
      }
    }, [isVisible, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage]);

    return (
      <Paper
        mt="md"
        bg="white"
        withBorder
        radius={"lg"}
        style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
      >
        <Table.ScrollContainer
          minWidth={800}
          h={`calc(100vh - 80px - 4rem)`}
          className={css({
            ".mantine-ScrollArea-viewport": { paddingBottom: 0 },
          })}
        >
          <Table
            className={css({
              "tbody tr:nth-child(even)": {
                background: colors.tailwind_gray[0],
              },
            })}
            verticalSpacing="md"
            horizontalSpacing="xl"
            withRowBorders={false}
          >
            <Table.Thead
              h="4rem"
              c="white"
              bg={colors.tailwind_indigo[6]}
              style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, zIndex: 1 }}
            >
              {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                <Table.Tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                    <Table.Th
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      key={header.id}
                      onClick={() => {
                        header.column.toggleSorting();
                      }}
                    >
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                      {{
                        asc: " ",
                        desc: " ",
                      }[header.column.getIsSorted() as string] ?? null}
                    </Table.Th>
                  ))}
                </Table.Tr>
              ))}
            </Table.Thead>
            <Table.Tbody
              style={{
                maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 134px)",
                overflowY: "auto",
              }}
              className={css({
                "& tr:hover": {
                  transition: "background .1s ease",
                  background: `${colors.tailwind_gray[1]} !important`,
                },
              })}
            >
              {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <Table.Tr style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} key={row.id}>
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <Table.Td
                      key={cell.id}
                      onClick={() => {
                        cell.column.id !== "action" && row.toggleSelected();
                      }}
                    >
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </Table.Td>
                  ))}
                </Table.Tr>
              ))}
            </Table.Tbody>
          </Table>

          {(hasNextPage || isRefetching || isLoading) && (
            <Skull
              skullAmount={isLoading ? 10 : 3}
              ref={skullComponentRef}
              px="xs"
            />
          )}
          {fetchStatus === "idle" && !hasNextPage && (
            <Flex
              py="lg"
              gap="xs"
              h="100%"
              align="center"
              tt="capitalize"
              justify="center"
              c="tailwind_submarine.9"
              bg="tailwind_submarine.0"
            >
              <RiDatabase2Line size={25} />
              <Text>no further records found.</Text>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Table.ScrollContainer>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
);

const Skull = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, BoxProps & { skullAmount: number }>(
  ({ skullAmount, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Box ref={ref} {...props}>
        {Array(skullAmount)
          .fill(null)
          .flatMap((_, key) => {
            return <Skeleton h="3.5rem" mt="xs" key={key} />;
          })}
      </Box>
    );
  }
);

export default TableComponent;
```

**here it's being used**

```
import {
  Menu,
  Modal,
  Flex,
  Title,
  Stack,
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  ActionIcon,
  useMantineTheme,
} from "@mantine/core";
import { useQueryClient, useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { IRetailer } from "@/providers/onboardingformprovider";
import { RiDeleteBin6Line, RiEdit2Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { createColumnHelper } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { BsThreeDotsVertical } from "react-icons/bs";
import TableComponent, { FetchFn } from "./table";
import { useDisclosure } from "@mantine/hooks";
import { useState } from "react";

interface Product
  extends Pick<
    IRetailer,
    | "productname"
    | "priceperunit"
    | "productquantity"
    | "productcategory"
    | "productdescription"
  > {
  check?: any;
  action?: any;
}

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Product>();

const ProductsList = () => {
  const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState<Product>();
  const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([
    {
      productname: "one",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 1",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "two",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 2",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "three",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 3",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "four",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 4",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "five",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 5",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "six",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 6",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "seven",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 7",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "eight",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 8",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "nine",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 9",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "ten",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 10",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "eleven",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 1",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "twelve",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 2",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "thirteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 3",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "fourteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 4",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "fifteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 5",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "sixteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 6",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "seventeen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 7",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "eighteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 8",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "nineteen",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 9",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
    {
      productname: "twenty",
      priceperunit: 10,
      productcategory: "test 10",
      productdescription: "test 1",
      productquantity: 10,
    },
  ]);
  const { colors } = useMantineTheme();
  const client = useQueryClient();

  const DeleteProductsMuation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () =>
      Promise.resolve(
        setProducts((products) => {
          return products.filter(
            (product) => selectedProduct?.productname !== product.productname
          );
        })
      ),
    onSuccess: () => {
      client.resetQueries({
        queryKey: ["products"],
      });
    },
  });

  const columns = [
    columnHelper.accessor("check", {
      header: ({ table }) => (
        <Checkbox
          color="tailwind_indigo.4"
          checked={table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected()}
          indeterminate={table.getIsSomeRowsSelected()}
          onChange={() => {
            table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected();
          }}
        />
      ),
      cell: ({ row }) => <Checkbox checked={row.getIsSelected()} readOnly />,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("productname", {
      cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
      header: "Product Name",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("productcategory", {
      cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
      header: "Product Category",
      enableSorting: true,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("productquantity", {
      cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
      header: "Product Quantity",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("priceperunit", {
      cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
      header: "Price",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("action", {
      header: "Action",
      cell: ({ row }) => (
        <Menu
          shadow="xl"
          radius="md"
          width={220}
          position="bottom-end"
          styles={{
            dropdown: {
              border: "1px solid",
              borderColor: colors.tailwind_gray[0],
            },
            item: {
              padding: ".5rem",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Menu.Target>
            <ActionIcon
              color="tailwind_gray.2"
              variant="outline"
              size="2.5rem"
              radius="xl"
              c="black"
            >
              <BsThreeDotsVertical />
            </ActionIcon>
          </Menu.Target>
          <Menu.Dropdown>
            <Menu.Item
              leftSection={
                <RiEdit2Line
                  size={16}
                  color="var(--mantine-color-tailwind_gray-6)"
                />
              }
            >
              Edit Product
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item
              color="red"
              leftSection={<RiDeleteBin6Line size={15} />}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedProduct(row.original);
                open();
              }}
            >
              Delete Product
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu.Dropdown>
        </Menu>
      ),
    }),
  ];

  const fetchProducts: FetchFn<Product> = async ({ pageParam }) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      // !add offset and limit/length should be statically type like (20 or 7), offset should be the pageParam when fetching from database multiplying the two should do it such as(offset(pageParam * size) and limit(size))
      const size = 7;
      const start = pageParam * size;
      const end = start + size;
      const slicedProducts = products.slice(start, end);

      return resolve(slicedProducts);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TableComponent
        columns={columns}
        queryKey={["products"]}
        queryFn={fetchProducts}
      />
      <Modal
        radius={"xl"}
        opened={opened}
        onClose={close}
        withCloseButton={false}
      >
        <Modal.Body>
          <Stack>
            <Title size="h2" fz="lg" fw="500">
              Are you sure you want to delete "{selectedProduct?.productname}"?
            </Title>
            <Flex gap=".5rem">
              <Button
                color="tailwind_gray"
                variant="outline"
                onClick={close}
                radius="xl"
                w="100%"
              >
                Discard
              </Button>
              <Button
                w="100%"
                color="red"
                radius="xl"
                onClick={() => {
                  close();
                  DeleteProductsMuation.mutate();
                }}
              >
                Delete
              </Button>
            </Flex>
          </Stack>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductsList;
```

**the sorting icons " "
" " visually change their appearance based on the sorting state but the columns are not being visually sorted from ascending to descending order and vice versa. I'm using "useInfiniteQuery" hook**

tried other examples online, the code seems to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

**this bit was missing**

```
  const table = useReactTable({
  columns,
  data: flatData,
  state: { sorting: sortingState, columnFilters, globalFilter },
  onSortingChange: setSortingState,
  getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
  onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
  getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),  <=========
});
```